# Let $X=$ a normed space & $A\subseteq X$ such that $X-A$ is a subspace. Prove that $A$ is either dense or empty.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $A\subseteq X$ such that $X-A$ is a linear subspace. Prove that $A$ is either dense or empty.

(Please give some hints/ways to prove. I tried like this: I assumed that A is not dense then I tried to prove X-A is not a linear subspace of X, but could not prove it.)

Comment: This boils down to proving that every nonempty open subset of a normed space is a spanning subset.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call $Y=X\setminus A$. Suppose $A\neq \emptyset$.

First: $0\not\in A$ but there exists a sequence $a_n\in A$ such that $a_n\to 0$. In fact suppose by contradiction that there is a ball $B_r(0)\subseteq Y$; since $Y$ is a subspace, this implies $Y=X$ and $A=\emptyset$, that contradicts the hypothesis.

Second: take $0\neq x_0\in Y$. The sequence $(a_n+x_0)\not\in Y$, otherwise $a_n\in Y$. So $(a_n+x_0)\in A$ and by the first point $(a_n+x_0)\to x_0$.

Hence we obtain: or $A=\emptyset$, or for all $y\in Y$ there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $y$, that is $A$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: If $\emptyset\neq A\subset X$ and $X-A$ is a linear subspace, then $A$ is dense in $X$.

Hint 2: Define $B=X-A$. You just need to prove 
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0~\forall x\in B~\exists a\in A~:~\|x-a\|\leq\varepsilon.
$$
Hint 3:

> For $\varepsilon>0$ choose some $\tilde a\in A$ such that $\|\tilde a\|<\varepsilon$. Then $a:=x+\tilde a\in A$ is useful for Hint 2.

**Proof:**

> Consider $\emptyset\neq A\subset X$ and define $B:=X-A$. We prove that $A$ is dense in $X$ if $B$ is a linear subspace.
>
> **Claim 1:** For $a\in A$ holds $a\neq 0$ and $\lambda a\in A$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb K-\{0\}$.
>
> *Proof of Claim 1*:
>
> First $0\in B$ since $B$ is a linear subspace of $X$. Therefore $a\neq 0$. Now suppose there exists $\lambda_0\in\mathbb K-\{0\}$ such that $\lambda_0 a\in B$. Since $B$ is a linear subspace, we get $\mu\lambda_0 a\in B$ for all $\mu\in\mathbb K$. Especially $a=\lambda_0^{-1}\lambda_0a\in B$, which is a contradiction since $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
>
> $\Box$
>
> **Claim 2:** If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $a+b\in A$.
>
> *Proof of claim 2:*
>
> Suppose $b+a\in B$ then there exists $\hat b\in B$ such that $a+b=\hat b$ and therefore $a=\hat b-b\in B$ since $B$ is a linear subspace. This is again a contradiction.
>
> $\Box$
>
> Let be $\varepsilon>0$ and $\hat a\in A$ arbitrary. Define $\tilde a=\frac{\varepsilon}{\|\hat a\|}\hat a$. Then $\|\tilde a\|=\varepsilon$ and by claim 1 $\tilde a\in A$. Now let be $x\in X$. If $x\in A$ we define $a=x$ and are done. If $x\in B$  we define $a=x+\tilde a$. By claim 2 we get $a\in A$ and $$\|x-a\|=\|\tilde a\|=\varepsilon.$$